# Spark disproportionate failure rate across nodes

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm running a spark standalone cluster across 21 nodes. The first worker has 12 available cores and the subsequent 20 workers have 4 cores each. My concern is that the node with 12 cores has a 0 failure rate for assigned tasks while all the other nodes have a failure rate of approximately 50%. Additionally, the 12 core worker is processing tasks at approx. 15x rate vs the other nodes. My question is thus: Is this failure rate a consequence of my configuration settings and if so, how can improve the task completion rate for the nodes that have 4 cores vs. the 12 core node? The configuration settings are supplied at runtime in the spark instantiation argument:

```
spark = (
    SparkSession
    .Builder()
    .appName('AnomalyDetection')
    .master('spark://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:7077')
    .config('spark.sql.session.timeZone', 'UTC')
    .config('spark.executor.memory','10G')
    .config('spark.ui.showConsoleProgress', True)
    .getOrCreate()
)
```

Here is an image from the spark Executors UI:
[image]

The UDF that is being processed is a derivative function of facebook's prophet library and I'm running approximately 700k time series analyses. Of note, the process does finish with all failed tasks being reran. The errors that I'm seeing in the stdout log are either:

```
ERROR ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Failed to get block(s) from ip org.apache.spark.ExectuorDeadException: The relative remote executor(Id: x), which maintains the block data to fetch is dead.
```

even though the executor is alive, or:

```
ERROR RetryingBlockTransferor: Exception while beginning fetch of x outstanding blocks
```

Happy to provide more information if necessary.

Comment: How did you even set 1 executor to have 12 cores and the others to have 4 cores?

Comment: I didn't set any specific parameters. My understanding is that the default settings leverage the maximum amount of cores available in each executor.

Comment: the error messages you sent are uninformative

are there no other error messages?

in your code also set "spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("DEBUG")" to see more information in the logs